# I want to increase the size of the icon thats already inside of a button. The size of the text inside the button (fontsize) should not change with it

Tags: css

his is the CSS code that I already have in place for fixed-sized buttons. I want to increase the size of the icon inside of these buttons. The style of the button is |text + icon|. Thank you

```css
.nectar-button.fixed-size {
    width: 250px;
    height: 75px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Please click "Run code snippet" and see if the code snippet recreates the issue you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

give another class name on icon tag and give css like:

```
.fa-home{font-size: 20px;}
.btn{font-size: 15px;color: black;background-color: orange;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>demo</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  .fa-home{font-size: 20px;}
  .btn{font-size: 15px;color: black;background-color: orange;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</button>
</body>
</html>
```

try these code, I think your problem will be solved, Thank you.

Comment: what if i am using wordpress, and so just adding a class on the page settings. a noob talking.